# Is is okay to say "reconciliation myself"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

If you reconcile yourself to an unpleasant situation, you accept it, although it does not make you happy to do so. So I think I could use this expression as in "He reconciled himself to what happened to him."

When I use the noun, reconciliation, is it still used with the same meaning? For example,

> The **reconciliation to** what happened to him.
>
> The **reconciliation himself to** what happened to him.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the noun "reconciliation" in relation to one's self, you can say

> His reconciliation with himself took place already.

But that can be expressed better by using a compound noun:

> His **self-reconciliation** happened after he understood his own motives.

That form, "self-reconciliation", would be the same referring to him, her, me or you.